# How to speed up nsolve or the bisection method?

Tags: python, optimization, sympy, solver, bisection

I am writing a program that requires a root finder of some sort, but every root finder I have used is unsatisfactorily slow. I'm looking for a way to speed this up.

I have used the SymPy's nsolve, and although this produces very precise results, it is very slow (if I do 12 iterations of my program it takes 12+ hours to run). I wrote my own bisection method, and this works much better, but is still very slow (12 iterations takes ~ 1 hour to run). I have been unable to find a symengine solver, or that is what I would be using. I will post both of my programs (with the bisection method and with nsolve). Any advice on how to speed this up is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code using nsolve:

```
from symengine import *
import sympy
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy import nsolve

trial = Matrix()

r, E1, E = symbols('r, E1, E')
H11, H22, H12, H21 = symbols("H11, H22, H12, H21")
S11, S22, S12, S21 = symbols("S11, S22, S12, S21")
low = 0
high = oo

integrate = lambda *args: sympy.N(sympy.integrate(*args))

quadratic_expression = (H11-E1*S11)*(H22-E1*S22)-(H12-E1*S12)*(H21-E1*S21)
general_solution = sympify(sympy.solve(quadratic_expression, E1)[0])


def solve_quadratic(**kwargs):
    return general_solution.subs(kwargs)


def H(fun):
    return -fun.diff(r, 2)/2 - fun.diff(r)/r - fun/r


psi0 = exp(-3*r/2)
trial = trial.row_insert(0, Matrix([psi0]))
I1 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*psi0*H(psi0), (r, low, high))
I2 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*psi0**2, (r, low, high))
E0 = I1/I2
print(E0)

for x in range(10):
    f1 = psi0
    f2 = r * (H(psi0)-E0*psi0)
    Hf1 = H(f1).simplify()
    Hf2 = H(f2).simplify()

    H11 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*Hf1, (r, low, high))
    H12 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*Hf2, (r, low, high))
    H21 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2*Hf1, (r, low, high))
    H22 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2*Hf2, (r, low, high))

    S11 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1**2, (r, low, high))
    S12 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*f2, (r, low, high))
    S21 = S12
    S22 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2**2, (r, low, high))

    E0 = solve_quadratic(
            H11=H11, H22=H22, H12=H12, H21=H21,
            S11=S11, S22=S22, S12=S12, S21=S21,
        )
    print(E0)

    C = -(H11 - E0*S11)/(H12 - E0*S12)
    psi0 = (f1 + C*f2).simplify()
    trial = trial.row_insert(x+1, Matrix([[psi0]]))

# Free ICI Part

h = zeros(x+2, x+2)
HS = zeros(x+2, 1)
S = zeros(x+2, x+2)

for s in range(x+2):
    HS[s] = H(trial[s]).simplify()

for i in range(x+2):
    for j in range(x+2):
        h[i, j] = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*trial[i]*HS[j], (r, low, high))

for i in range(x+2):
    for j in range(x+2):
        S[i, j] = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*trial[i]*trial[j], (r, low, high))

m = h - E*S
eqn = m.det()

roots = nsolve(eqn, float(E0))

print(roots)
```

Here is the code using my bisection method:

```
from symengine import *
import sympy
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy import nsolve

trial = Matrix()

r, E1, E = symbols('r, E1, E')
H11, H22, H12, H21 = symbols("H11, H22, H12, H21")
S11, S22, S12, S21 = symbols("S11, S22, S12, S21")
low = 0
high = oo

integrate = lambda *args: sympy.N(sympy.integrate(*args))

quadratic_expression = (H11-E1*S11)*(H22-E1*S22)-(H12-E1*S12)*(H21-E1*S21)
general_solution = sympify(sympy.solve(quadratic_expression, E1)[0])


def solve_quadratic(**kwargs):
    return general_solution.subs(kwargs)


def bisection(fun, a, b, tol):
    NMax = 100000
    f = Lambdify(E, fun)
    FA = f(a)
    for n in range(NMax):
        p = (b+a)/2
        FP = f(p)
        if FP == 0 or abs(b-a)/2 < tol:
            return p
        if FA*FP > 0:
            a = p
            FA = FP
        else:
            b = p
    print("Failed to converge to desired tolerance")



def H(fun):
    return -fun.diff(r, 2)/2 - fun.diff(r)/r - fun/r


psi0 = exp(-3*r/2)
trial = trial.row_insert(0, Matrix([psi0]))
I1 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*psi0*H(psi0), (r, low, high))
I2 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*psi0**2, (r, low, high))
E0 = I1/I2
print(E0)

for x in range(11):
    f1 = psi0
    f2 = r * (H(psi0)-E0*psi0)
    Hf1 = H(f1).simplify()
    Hf2 = H(f2).simplify()

    H11 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*Hf1, (r, low, high))
    H12 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*Hf2, (r, low, high))
    H21 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2*Hf1, (r, low, high))
    H22 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2*Hf2, (r, low, high))

    S11 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1**2, (r, low, high))
    S12 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*f2, (r, low, high))
    S21 = S12
    S22 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2**2, (r, low, high))

    E0 = solve_quadratic(
            H11=H11, H22=H22, H12=H12, H21=H21,
            S11=S11, S22=S22, S12=S12, S21=S21,
        )
    print(E0)

    C = -(H11 - E0*S11)/(H12 - E0*S12)
    psi0 = (f1 + C*f2).simplify()
    trial = trial.row_insert(x+1, Matrix([[psi0]]))

# Free ICI Part

h = zeros(x+2, x+2)
HS = zeros(x+2, 1)
S = zeros(x+2, x+2)

for s in range(x+2):
    HS[s] = H(trial[s]).simplify()

for i in range(x+2):
    for j in range(x+2):
        h[i, j] = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*trial[i]*HS[j], (r, low, high))

for i in range(x+2):
    for j in range(x+2):
        S[i, j] = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*trial[i]*trial[j], (r, low, high))

m = h - E*S
eqn = m.det()

roots = bisection(eqn, E0 - 1, E0, 10**(-15))

print(roots)
```

As I said, they both work as they are supposed to, but they do so very slowly.

Comment: Clearly each iteration is extremely expensive. Rather than focusing on improving the bisection method, would it make sense to focus on speeding up the function evaluations?

Comment: I open to speeding up any part of the program, but right now the bottle neck is certainly the root solvers. Do you have any ideas in mind?

Comment: What I mean is, your bisection search calls a function `fun` multiple times, once per iteration. From your question, I gather that it takes 1+ hours to do 12 iterations, meaning 12 function calls. To me, this suggests that the bisection method -- i.e., the outer loop -- is not the problem, but rather the function that you are calling -- the inner function -- is quite slow.

Comment: Also your tolerance seems very small -- `10**(-15)` -- is such a small tolerance essential? If not, making it larger will obviously speed your code.

Comment: The bisection method is only called once, regardless of the number of iterations. It's called only at the very end, after the loop has completed. However, with more evaluations, the function fun gets larger and larger (n iterations results in an (n+1)x(n+1) determinant that is set equal to zero). That small of tolerance is essential, and I would eventually like to expand this to an even larger precision (around 30 digits or so), but 15 digits works for now.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by an "iteration". I understand you only call the bisection method once. But when you call it, how many times does the `for n` loop execute? I thought you were saying it only executed 12 times and that took hours. Is that right?

Comment: Ahh, I see the misunderstanding. I am referring to the for loop in the main block of code, completely separate from the bisection method. The for n loop, on the other hand, executes until it converges on a root, or hits the maximum number of iterations. When I refer to iterations, I am referring to the for x loop.

Comment: OK I see. In any case, I still stand by my suggestion that it might be better to improve the efficiency of the code that the bisection search *calls* rather than the bisection code itself. And it seems isuruf’s answer does that excellently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some optimizations for your code,

1. Use `Lambdify(E, fun, cse=True)` to make use of Common Subexpression Elimination
2. Add `pi = sympify(sympy.N(pi))` to use a numeric value of `pi`. Keeping `pi` as symbolic hurts because of large expressions.
3. Change `.simplify` calls to `.expand` calls.
4. Your expressions for integration have a special form. They have the special form, `integrate(r**n * exp(-p*r), (r, 0, inf)` which can be integrated easily.

```
In [21]: var("n, r, p", positive=True)                                                                                                                                
Out[21]: (n, r, p)

In [22]: integrate(q*r**n*exp(-p*r), (r, 0, oo))                                                                                                                      
Out[22]: p**(-n)*q*gamma(n + 1)/p
```

You can get the advantage of this using a hack like this below. (Ideally sympy should be able to do this faster, but sympy doesn't do a good job on this. I ran into the same issue last summer when trying to solve Dirac and Schrödinger equations symbolically to debug my numeric code. I assume you are trying to do something similar)

```
def integrate(*args):
    args = list(args)
    expr = args[0].expand()
    r = sympy.S(args[1][0])
    limits = args[1][1:]
    p = sympy.Wild("p")
    n = sympy.Wild("n")
    q = sympy.Wild("q")
    pattern = q * r**n * sympy.exp(p*r)
    terms = expr.args
    if not expr.is_Add:
        terms = [expr]
    result = 0
    for arg in terms:
        d = sympy.S(arg).match(pattern)
        if d is None:
            result += sympy.N(sympy.integrate(arg, args[1]))
            continue
        if d[p].is_number and d[q].is_number and d[n].is_number:
            ex = d[q]*(-d[p])**(-d[n])/d[p]*sympy.lowergamma(d[n]+1, -d[p]*r)
            result += sympify(sympy.factorial(d[n])*d[q]/(-d[p])**(d[n]+1))
        else:
            result += sympy.N(sympy.integrate(arg, args[1]))
    return result
```

These 4 changes reduces the time to 16 seconds for me.

Comment: isuruf, thank you very much for that very good answer. The speed is much better, but for some reason all of the integrals seam to have lost precision on the 15th digit. Do you have any idea how we can take care of that? Ideally I'd like to be able to calculate the energies to 30+ digits (if it's only 15, that will certainly do for now). On a side note, I am using this for solving the Dirac-Coulomb equation and Schrodinger equation. What method were you using to solve them when working on this last summer? I've been doing research based on the Free Iterative Configuration Interaction method.

Comment: For higher precision, use `sympy.N(pi, 30)` instead of `sympy.N(pi)`. Same for other N cals.

(I was writing a FEM code using SCF.)

Comment: You can find the modified code at https://gist.github.com/isuruf/2684f352ad7cc8ab1d6c19e77ff3cd06 for higher precision

Comment: So that is giving some very strange results when I run it on my end. The first E0 calculation is certainly more precise, but after that the answers are wildly incorrect. They should continue to approach -1/2 from above, but they are bouncing all over the place and giving imaginary parts (everything should be real).

Comment: Are you using symengine v0.4.0?

Comment: Yes I am, and Python 3.7

Comment: That's weird. I don't see any imaginary parts. Can you open an issue at github.com/symengine/symengine.py with your output?